# Concrete universal turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

I read about universal turing machines in the internet, but I did not find a concrete listing of a universal turing machine and a descreption, how a specific turing machine
has to be coded that the universal machines simulates it. Does anyone know a suitable
link ?

I found the following description of the smallest universal turing machine :

```
A   B
```

0   P1,R,B  P2,L,A

1   P2,L,A  P2,R,B

2   P1,L,A  P0,R,A

As it has no halting state, how can it simulate a halting turing machine ?
 (Sorry for the bad format)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine#Example_of_universal-machine_coding

Comment: I found the description of the storage, but not the u-machine itself.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397596000771

Comment: There are different kind of universality. I don't think that this example is the Turing universality. Where did you find this example ?

Comment: This is weak universality, not Turing universality : you have to encode the input of the machine in an infinite repetitive pattern. The output must be constantly observed until something happens that can be analyzed as "the simulated program halted", because as you did observe, there is no halt state in this example. So it's much less than usual Turing universality.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but such a machine is completely useless, or am I wrong ?

Comment: Are the turing machines in your links turing-universal ?

Comment: For any practical purposes, yes, it's useless at this time. But for a better knowledge of what is computation, it's very useful. Yes my answer is about usual Turing universality.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: It's very hard to find small universal Turing machines. When researchers can't solve something, they try something easier. That's why they tried to find some small weakly universal machines as your example. But it doesn't help much for real universality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397596000771 contains complete descriptions of some universal Turing machines.

On page 8 of the pdf (page 222) you have an example of a machine with 24 states and 2 symbols.
On page 10 of the pdf (page 224) you have an example of a machine with 10 states and 3 symbols.

Comment: In this link, the listing is still not visible. What can I do to get acess to it ?

Comment: Don't you have a download PDF link at the top (just under Home| Publications)?

Comment: Yes, but is it free ?

Comment: for me it seems to be.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.